# What is the proper use of super.call(this)

Tags: javascript, class, call, super

I have a class function (not originally developed by me)...

```
function Project()
{
  Project.super.call(this);
  // this._some_var = null;
  /* other initial vars */
  ...
  return DefensiveObject.create(this); // see comment below
}

function initialize()
  {
     //*******Initialize Project************
  }
  ...

return Project;
```

This function is part of a module called "Project.js" included by running node main.js.

```
  return DefensiveObject.create(this); // not return Object.create(this)
```

DefensiveObject is a class to prevent objects from getting or
setting properties that are not explicitly setup in the class.

The main.js calls Project.initialize() which resides within my Project class.

My question is why would there be a need to call "Project.super.call(this);"?

Comment: Is this inside a `class Project { .. }` block? The constructor should be named `constructor`, not the same as the class.

Comment: There is no `Project.super` property by default. What inheritance framework are you using? Read its documentation for how to use this. And why don't you just use standard ES6 `class`es with `super()`?

Comment: "*`return Object.create(this);`*" - don't do that. A constructor should not `return` anything.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this is still not enough information to answer. Please provide the full code as a complete [mcve]

Comment: super.call is fragile, as the experts all have showed us.  ;)  (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: I commented out the super.call(this) line and the entire program still works so I think the answer is that the original developer added it by mistake. Ugh!

Comment: @flyermakerpro Pretty certainly they didn't do it by mistake, but you still haven't shown us the code that creates the `Project.super` property in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Javascript the reserved word super is used on ES6 classes for referencing the parent of a child class, it doesn't makes sense to use it referencing a function.

please read this article where the usage of super is explained

https://jordankasper.com/understanding-super-in-javascript/

also this medium article can help you
https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/super-and-extends-in-javascript-es6-understanding-the-tough-parts-6120372d3420

Answer (score 0):

The Project.super.call(this) line was a way to allow use of a dispose method in a "Disposable" class (not included in the original question) which allowed for a clean up of code from memory.